# How to initialize an empty struct?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I'm lost at how to initialize the struct below? Basically I want to create an empty variable that represents the struct below, but the values should be optional/nil, but i have no idea how to go about it.

```
// MARK: - Main
struct Main: Codable {
    let meta: Meta
    let objects: [Object]
}

// MARK: - Meta
struct Meta: Codable {
    let status: String
    let count, offset, totalcount: Int
}

// MARK: - Object
struct Object: Codable {
    let id:Int
    let url: String
    let displayname: String
    let inventory: [Inventory]
    let media: [Media]
}


// MARK: - Inventory
struct Inventory: Codable {
   let id, warehouseid, instock, threshold: Int
    let reserved: Int
    let coordinates, note: String
    let prodno: Int
    let lastinventory: String
    let soldout, onpurchaseorders, generation: Int
    let created, changed: String
}

// MARK: - Media
struct Media: Codable {
    let id, prodno: Int
    let webpath: String
    let slot: Int
    let type, extdata: String
    let ctime, xsize, ysize, mediasetid: Int
    let alt, title: String
    let generation: Int
    let created, changed: String
}
```

With the below code I get the error message "no exact matches in call to initializer, and a bunch of other errors if i change the code.

```
var sökresultat3 = Main3()
```

Comment: "Basically I want to create an empty variable that represents the struct below" you probably don't actually want that. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Alexander I agree that excessive use of optionals may be bad here, but are you objecting to a "default" `Main` that is empty? That seems a very natural thing to have. What you're concern here?

Comment: I don't know what a `Main` is, so it's hard to tell. But the "make all fields nullable" smell has got my attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the properties to be Optionals, then you have to declare them that way. `Int` means you want an Int. If you want an Optional Int, then declare it `Int?`.

That said, I would be very thoughtful about creating so many Optionals, and particularly optional arrays and strings. Is there a difference in your system between "no inventory" (`nil`) and "an empty list of inventory" (`[]`)? Or "no name" (`nil`) and "empty name" (`""`)? If these are the same, then you often will prefer to just have default values, not optional values. Optionals add a lot of complexity that you may not need.

As an example of default values, using `var` will make this much simpler and give you the initializers you're hoping for:

```
struct Main: Codable {
    var meta = Meta()
    var objects: [Object] = []
}

// MARK: - Meta
struct Meta: Codable {
    var status = ""
    var count = 0
    var offset = 0
    var totalcount = 0
}
```

If you do make these optional, then `var` again will create the initializers you're looking for:

```
struct Main: Codable {
    var meta: Meta?
    var objects: [Object]?
}
```

As a rule, simple data structs that have no logic in them should declare their properties `var`. There are some exceptions, such as Identifiable structs, which should make their `id` be `let` because their `id` has some special meaning. But as a rule, making structs excessively `let` just makes them hard to use without gaining any benefits. (Values types are never shared, so mutation is not a problem.)

If you still want to use `let`, you'll need to define your own `init` by hand.

Comment: Hi Rob! Thanks for the answer.

I've tried declaring everything as ?, but i still get an error when i try to initialize it with var sökresultat3 = Main3(), it says "Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call, insert 'from: <#Decoder#>.

Comment: Codable doesn't impact this `init`. If you use `var`, you won't have to write your own init. The problem is that "`let` with a value" is treated as a constant, not a default.

Comment: @RobNapier what is the complexity Optionals add in this context?
I think default values add more complexity, because I will need to ask isStringEmpty? or isNumberZero? etc... 
and use ternary expression later in code to choose alternative values for each scenario, instead of just using the  ??  expression for all types

Answer (score 1):

If all your struct's properties are optionals, and you make them all `var`s, Swift will create an intializer that defaults all your properties to nil. It is as if you defined your struct as follows:

```
struct AStruct {
    var a: Int?
    var string: String?
    
    //You don't have to define this initializer if all your properties are var Optionals
    init(a: Int? = nil, string: String? = nil) {
        self.a = a
        self.string = string
    }
}
```

You can invoke that initializer like this:

```
var aStruct = AStruct()
```

As Alexander pointed out, just because you **can** do this does not mean that you **should** do it. It does not seem like good practice.

Comment: Swift will write this initializer for you automatically given this struct. There's no need to write it.

Comment: I think this is a huge anti-pattern, I wouldn't recommending this. Devs from foreign languages (where everything is default initialized to 0, false, null, etc.) will reach for something like this, but it's almost never what they actually need.

Answer (score 0):

Change `main` to this

```
struct Main: Codable {
var meta: Meta?
var objects: [Object]?
}
```

Comment: Hi Luca!! Thanks for the answer. I've tried this but i still get an error when i try to initialize it with var sökresultat3 = Main3(), it says "Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call, insert 'from: <#Decoder#>.

Comment: Just editited the question, let me know if it works